# A class definition for a date class that contains three integer data members:month,day,year

Tags: c#

I am not sure what they are asking for here. An example would be great.

Here is the complete list of requirements. I am working through an exercise in a book I have been reading but I have read the chapter over and over but I just cant make sense out of it.

1. A class definition for a date class that contains three integer data members:month,day,year
2. One constructor that assigns the date 1/1/2000 to any new object that does not recieve any arguments.
3. One constructor thats accepts month and day arguements and uses a default year of 2004
4. One constructor thats accepts month, day,and year arguements
5. Each constructor should also output a message to the user stating which constructor is currently being used.
6. A method that displays the values in the date object.

Comment: is this homework?  what is your best guess?

Comment: A guess - DateTime class has Month, Day, Year properties (which are all integers). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: this is one of the requirements of the program, but i am not sure what they are wanting.

Comment: so are you saying class DateTime and month,day, and year are methods inside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WeirdRequirements
{
    int m_year, m_month, m_day;
    public delegate void MessagePrinter(string message);
    public MessagePrinter PrintMessage = Console.WriteLine;

    public WeirdRequirements()
    {
        m_year = 2000;
        m_month = 1;
        m_day = 1;
        PrintMessage("default");
    }

    public WeirdRequirements(int Month, int Day)
    {
        m_year = 2004;
        m_month = Month;
        m_day = Day;
        PrintMessage("int Month, int Day");
    }

    public WeirdRequirements(int Year, int Month, int Day)
    {
        m_year = Year;
        m_month = Month;
        m_day = Day;
        PrintMessage("int Year, int Month, int Day");
    }

    public void PrintValues()
    {
        PrintMessage(string.Format("Year={0} Month={1} Day={2}", m_year, m_month, m_day));
    }
}
```