# An example of what they are asking would be great

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A class definition for a date class that contains three integer data members:month,day,year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809520/a-class-definition-for-a-date-class-that-contains-three-integer-data-membersmont)

I am not sure what they are asking for here. An example would be great.

Here is the complete list of requirements. I am working through an exercise in a book I have been reading but I have read the chapter over and over but I just cant make sense out of it.

```
1.A class definition for a date class that contains three integer data members:month,day,year

2.One constructor that assigns the date 1/1/2000 to any new object that does not recieve any arguments.

3.One constructor thats accepts month and day arguements and uses a default year of 2004
4.One constructor thats accepts month, day,and year arguements
5.Each constructor should also output a message to the user stating which constructor is currently being used.
6.A method that displays the values in the date object
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Which parts of which requirements don't make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

1

```
public class myDate
{
  public int day {get;set;}
  public int month {get;set;}
  public int year {get;set;}
}
```

2

```
public myDate()
{
  this.day = 1;
  this.month = 1;
  this.year = 2000;
}
```

3

```
public myDate(int day, int month)
{
  this.day = day;
  this.month = month;
  this.year = 2004;
}
```

4

```
public myDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
  this.day = day;
  this.month = month;
  this.year = year;
}
```

6

```
  public DateTime getDate()
  {
    return new DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day);
  }
```

Comment: you forgot the constructors ;)